# How to test if a TransactionHash is valid using web3?

Tags: web3js, transactions

Is there any way I can tell whether a transaction hash is valid or not?
For eg,

> 0x2592cf699903e83bfd664aa4e339388fd044fe31643a85037be803a5d162729f is valid transaction Hash whereas 0x62720366ef403c9891e2bfbd5358ee3c8a57b113 is not.

How to test programmatically whether a transaction hash is valid or not **using** **web3**?

I wish to have a function like:

```
isValidTransactionHash(String txHash){
// if transaction hash is valid return true else false
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This method will only validate if the transaction hash has the right characters in the right length, it does not check the blockchain. Useful for string validation on user inputs.

```
function validate_txhash(addr)
{
  return /^0x([A-Fa-f0-9]{64})$/.test(addr);
}
```

This regex was supplied by this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/34286/50301

Answer (score 5):

I would try with `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` inside a `try`-`catch` block:

```
try {
  var txR = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x62720366ef403c9891e2bfbd5358ee3c8a57b11");
  if (txR.blockNumber == undefined)
    throw "transaction receipt not found";
}
catch(e) {
  console.log("invalid tx receipt: " + e);
}
```

Comment: But `getTransactionteceipt` is not meant for that. It returns null for any string starting with '0x' followed by any string of length 64. Like `0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` and `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` all are valid transaction hashes according ti this but actually  they are not.

Comment: then simply check for some expected child, such as `blockNumber`. I added that to the example code.

Comment: That's not the way man. See, `getTransactionReceipt` returns null for both an incorrect transaction Hash as well as the transaction that is not mined yet. So checking this way will declare all transaction Hashes which are valid but not yet mined as invalid.Hope you understand.

Comment: Did you test the code that I updated before posting my previous comment? I did and see it working. Please check again.

Comment: I tested that. If you pass a transactionHash that is not yet mined (but transaction hash is valid), the value of txR will be null, and since in next line when you try to access blockNumber of null, this will give an error. and in this case, a valid transaction has is also declared as invalid. Please check the code with a valid but unmined transaction.

Comment: Because hashes are irreversible, there's no way to know if a transaction hash is "valid" with just the hash. This may be the best that one can get.

Comment: So you don't want to check if the txHash is valid but if it's known to the node you're connected to but not necessarily mind yet. Very different thing. In that case try `.getTransaction` and same as above check for some child property.

Comment: I guess @MatthewSchmidt is right. We probably can't check if a transaction is valid because hashes are irreversible. So to check if tx hash is valid we could check for the string should start with `0x` and followed by 62 characters would be enough.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The short one is the @Jacob post. And there is also a long one, You can validate with a regex like Jacob suggest, after this you can also check if the transaction is in the blockchain with getTransactionReceipt and you may want to check the mempool for unconfirmed transaction. In this way you have a full picture of the transaction status.

Answer (score 1):

```
const search = async hash => {
    const re = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;
    // 0x + 64 bytes
    if(hash && hash.length === 66 && re.test(hash)) {
      const item = await contract.methods.getItemByHash(hash).call()
     
    }
  }
```

Comment: The regex doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @Ismael why? I do not see any issue

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't test it correctly.

Comment: @Ismael I do not accept plain sorry :) just upvote the answer :)