# What is the regex to validate an Ethereum transaction hash?

Tags: transactions

I am building an application which requires user to paste the transaction hash of a transaction. But i want a regex string i could pass to the pattern attribute of the input element that receives it to validate it.
What is the general regexp that validates ethereum transaction hash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if an Ethereum address is valid?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks It's not a duplicate; this question is about the transaction hash, not the address. I don't see a regex for the transaction hash in that answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right :-) I read "regex" and ignored everything else :-) Removed duplicate vote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This regex should do the trick:

`/^0x([A-Fa-f0-9]{64})$/`

Comment: Keep in mind this only validates if the search contains only the right characters in the right length, not if a transaction exists on the blockchain.

Comment: @Nick this is clear. Thats just what i want

Comment: I accepted the answer but i will rather go for /^(0x)?([A-Fa-f0-9]{64})$/ because it is also valid incase the source is from some of those who don't include the 0x prefix. Or do you think that should be considered invalid? The API i use to query the transactions accepts transaction IDs without the 0x

Comment: How can we implement this in Python?

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't specify the technology you are using, I would suggest validating it against the go-ethereum `hexutil` https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/common/hexutil/hexutil.go#L60

Here's a simple example written in golang:

```
// IsValid : validates transaction with go-ethereum utils
func (model *Transaction) IsValid() bool {
    _, err := hexutil.Decode(model.Hash)
    return err == nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

btw, if you want to validate an address instead of a transaction, the following regex does it:

`/^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$/`