# How can I validate if a transaction hash is valid using web3.py?

Tags: transactions, web3.py

How can I check whether a transaction hash is valid or not using Python [`web3.py`]?

The answers I found was in javascript, related:

- [How to test if a TransactionHash is valid using web3?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/15811/4575)
- [What is the regex to validate an Ethereum transaction hash?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34285/what-is-the-regex-to-validate-an-ethereum-transaction-hash/34286#34286)

Comment: Why can't you just check if the transaction with this hash exists on the chain ?

Comment: I don't want to check if the transaction hash exists on the chain, which will also consumes additional time to check from.

Comment: Considering a hash is just a bunch of characters with a specific length (the string), any string with said length is a valid transaction hash.

Comment: Besides length it should not contain any  invalid characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of `regex` at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/34286/4575:

> `/^0x([A-Fa-f0-9]{64})$/`

---

```py
import re

def is_transaction_valid(tx_hash) -> bool:
    pattern = re.compile(r"^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{64}")
    return bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, tx_hash))

tx_hash = "0xd65dc6bf6dcc111237f9acfbfa6003ea4a4d88f2e071f4307d3af81ae877f7be"
if is_transaction_valid(tx_hash):
    print(f"{tx_hash} is an valid transaction.")
else:
    print(f"{tx_hash} is NOT a valid transaction.")
```